# Change first colum of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to convert this numpy array:

```
array = np.array([[np.array([1]),2],[np.array([1]),2],[np.array([1]),2]])
print (array)
[[array([1]) 2]
 [array([1]) 2]
 [array([1]) 2]]
```

to this numpy array:

```
print(array)
[[1 2]
 [1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

How can I achieve this without a for loop?

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
first_col = array[:,0]
first_col = np.array([i[0] for i in first_col])
```

Comment: I wonder how you got this strange structure in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I don't even know if answering this is a good idea, since there must be a fundemental flaw in the design to even come up with a situation like this and the correct solution would be to fix that, rather than trying to mitigate the issue by converting the output.

Never-the-less, given the data, interestingly enough, it is possible to 'unpack' the structure using the `numpy` array method `.astype()`:

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([[np.array([1]),2],[np.array([1]),2],[np.array([1]),2]])
array = array.astype(int) # alt array = array.astype(float)
```

But, as stated above, this is treating the symptom of the problem, rather than the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `map` to convert it to a list:

```
map(lambda x: [list(x[0]), x[1]], array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[np.array([1]),2],
                [np.array([1]),2],
                [np.array([1]),2]])

np.array([[i[0][0], i[1]] for i in arr])

# array([[1, 2],
#        [1, 2],
#        [1, 2]])
```